# Creating an indicator on Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, powerpoint, dax

I have the following table in Power BI. I am trying to create the Status_Indicator column(Read Column) by creating a measure in Power BI that shows If an item is delivered then status_Indicator is 1 otherwise it is 0. The DAX that I created returns 1 for both items delivered and not delivered. Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what you have tried. Since you need a measure, you can try this.

```
status indicator = IF(MAX('Table Name'[Status]) = "Delivered",1,0)
```